# Detect changes for complex object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a BO with some dependent BO's (via navigation properties), which represent several linked tables in the database. For example, a Person main table, and Address, Education tables, linked via Person_Address, Person_Education tables, 1-to-many.

We need to track changes that occurs over the Person, Address, Education tables for the specific person. Any update in those three tables should update the Person.LastRecordUpdate date to the current date. I don't see any problems to track the Person table itself. However, we need to track changes in other two tables (Address, Education), which have the AddressId, EducationId PKs, and no PersonId (since they are linked with the primary table via intermediate tables). And saving in Address, Education happens in another dbcontext entity, that save of person. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using a swing table for a 1 to many table? Do you mean a many to many relationship(many users can have the same education or address)?

Answer (score 1):

I derive all of my business objects from a ModelBase that includes a `public virtual DateTime? LastModified` property.  It also implements the interface

```
public interface IHasLastModified
{
    DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Then I override `SaveChanges()` in my `DbContext` to look for anything being added or modified that implements `IHasLastModified`, and set the modified timestamp.

On a side note, EF is quirky about displaying `DbEntityValidationException` details in the debugger.  For that reason, in this code I also handle that
exception by building `errorList` that is straightforward to view in the debugger, and also log the details.  In my code, `logger` is an NLog logger.  You can
use any other logger, or remove that line.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
        {
            //logger.Info("Setting LastModified on " + entry.Entity.GetType().FullName);
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                IHasLastModified lastModified = entry.Entity as IHasLastModified;
                if (lastModified != null)
                    lastModified.LastModified = now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    } 
    catch (DbEntityValidationException valEx)
    {
        List<string> errorList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var error in valEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var entry in error.ValidationErrors)
            {
                errorList.Add(entry.PropertyName + ": " + entry.ErrorMessage);
            }

            logger.Error(string.Join(";", errorList));
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

> And saving in Address, Education happens in another dbcontext entity, that save of person.

It is very, very tricky to merge changes across multiple DbContext instances.  EF does not provide full support for all scenarios.

I strongly suggest avoiding this situation.  Pass a single instance of a DbContext around rather than attempting to merge changes from two DbContext images.

If you really want to try and manage changes that happen in two context instances, have a look at [this writeup](http://blog.maskalik.com/entity-framework/2013/12/23/entity-framework-updating-database-from-detached-objects/).  Note the concluding remark

> As of today EF does not support of full object graph merging, and leaves that for you to manage on your own.

Comment: I normally override the `SaveChanges` but that interface with `LastModified` it's an excellent idea. I'm going to implement it in my next projects!

Comment: Eric, how your solution helps in this situation: suppose, I have the following DB stuff: Person.LastRecordUpdate; I also have an address record in the Address table, which is linked - correct, many-to-many - with the Person table via Person_Address table. I modify the ZIP code in that address record, so how then I should be able to track it so I would be able to automatically update the Person.LastRecordUpdate value?

Comment: @TakhirMamirov: Every entity saved will have the timestamp automatically applied.  Change my `LastModified` to your `LastRecordUpdate`.  Doesn't matter if it is a parent or child.

Comment: Let me complicate the task. The MemberInfo table linked 1-to-1 with person. There's a fields MemberInfo.LastModified. Also there're those two satellite tables - Education, Address, linked with Person. Problem: when I modify the Education or Address entity in DB, I need MemberInfo.LastModified updated. Please share which classes should inherit that BaseModel, which not, and which of them should have the LastModified property. Note: not all BO need that property. Only MemberInfo.

Comment: Simple... each one that needs to have the timestamp automatically set inherits from ModelBase.